# Password update with Meteor Autoforms

Tags: meteor, passwords, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to make an account page where the user can update their profile info and/or update their password. I'm currently using this for the form:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" doc=profile id="myAccount" type="update"}}
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>My Account</legend>
                            {{> afQuickField name="username"}}
                            {{> afQuickField name="profile.firstName"}}
                            {{> afQuickField name="profile.lastName"}}
                            {{> afQuickField name="emails.0.address"}}
                            {{> afQuickField name="emails.0.verified" class="i-checks"}}
                            {{> afQuickField name="password"}}
                        </fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    {{/autoForm}}
```

From what I understand, I need to user Accounts.setPassword in order to update a users password. So I figured I'd have to use a hook for this, but the onSubmit hook doesn't work with the type update.

What's the best way to update a password with this kind of form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will something like this work: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#normal where contact form is the name of your form?

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  contactForm: {
    onSubmit: function (insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc) {
      if (customHandler(insertDoc)) {
        this.done();
      } else {
        this.done(new Error("Submission failed"));
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: onSubmit doesn't work with type="update". Your suggestion works if I change the submit type. Thanks!